# TERADATA as link server for SQL Server 2008 with Windows authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, teradata

Is it possible to create link server in SQL Server 2008 for Teradata using Windows authentication? Couldn't find any information about that. All examples in google use already specified user for connect.

Thanks.

Comment: As in Active Directory based LDAP Windows Authentication?

Comment: Have errors with that way. Have you manual for that?

Comment: What error message are you receiving? The user account you are using must exist on Teradata and be granted logon with NULL password, a special database grant required for external authentication with LDAP.

Comment: I want to create link server to teradata, that use windows authentication. I mean link server without certain user defined by password. For example, all users of certain ms sql server have same accounts and password on the certain teradata server. Is it possible to create link server which will dynamically specify what user gonna send sql query. So when user1 try to use openquery for teradata from ms sql server its gonna be only his session. When its gonna do user2 its gonna be session on teradata of user2. Do not want to get just one session for already specified user on teradata for all.

Comment: I meant impersonation for all users who gonna use linked server from ms sql to teradata.

Comment: I have error like 'your password or account is not valid'. However I can connect to teradata server directly with this account and password.

Comment: What is the logon mechanism being used when you connect directly to Teradata?

Comment: It is ldap mechanism.